# How to show one column value into multiple column by distinct that column by type or id

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "Price".

In this table, three types of prices i-e cash, credit, check prices and these prices show in column sale_type_price.

I want to display these prices in 3 different columns i-e cash price, credit price and check price:

```
  item_id  |   sale_type  | price
     01    |     3        |  10
     02    |     3        |  11
     01    |     6        |  20
     01    |     7        |  30
     02    |     6        |  22  
     02    |     7        |  22
```

This is my table and I want the result like this:

```
  item_id  | Cash Price | credit price| check price 
     01    |   10       |      20     |     30
     02    |   11       |      22     |     22
```

Can anyone assist me with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `case when expression`

```
select item_id, 
       max(case when sale_type=3 then price end) as CashPrice,
       max(case when sale_type=6 then price end) as creditprice,
       max(case when sale_type=7 then price end) as checkprice
from tablename
group by item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use joins to achieve the result

```
SELECT a.item_id, a.price AS CashPrice, b.price AS CreditPrice, c.price AS CheckPrice FROM Price a
LEFT JOIN Price b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND b.sale_type = 6
LEFT JOIN Price c ON a.item_id = c.item_id AND c.sale_type = 7
WHERE a.sale_type = 3
```